# Unintentional Multi-threading in Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am working with a `SettingsPane` that holds settings, and I have all my problems solved - except for one thing I apparently have no control over.

This is the relevant SettingsPane.xaml:

```xml
<ComboBox Name="Themes" SelectionChanged="SettingSelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Theme 1" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Theme 2" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Theme 3" />
</ComboBox>
```

This is my SettingsPane.xaml.cs:

```cs
public Settings()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = MainPage.Data;
    Themes.SelectedIndex = 0;
}

private void SettingSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"] = Themes.SelectedIndex;
    ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
}
```

I handle the `SignalDataChanged()` call in MainPage.xaml.cs:

```cs
public static MainPageVM Data = new MainPageVM();

public MainPage()
{
    Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.DataChanged += (a, o) =>
    {
        Data.Theme = (int) Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.RoamingSettings.Values["Theme"];
    };
}
```

`Theme` is stored in MainPageVM.cs:

```cs
private int _theme = 0;
public int Theme
{
    get { return _theme; }
    set
    {
        if (value == _theme) return;
        _theme = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Now, this is bound like this:

```cs
<Grid Background="{Binding Theme, Converter={StaticResource ThemeToBackground}}" Name="MainGrid">
```

It appears to be working, except for one thing.  When it hits the `OnPropertyChanged()` call in `Theme`'s setter, it crashes with this error:

> Additional information: The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THREAD))

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each window has a different thread associated with it; you should avoid referencing one page's view model from another page if there is data binding involved (you will need an adapter that pushes the changes onto the correct thread). [Edit] Also that particular event is being raised on a thread that isn't associated with any page.

Comment: Like one of these?

            `/*CoreApplication.MainView.CoreWindow.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
                });*/
            CoreApplication.MainView.Dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                ApplicationData.Current.SignalDataChanged();
            });`

Comment: Each page that listens to the data should have their own adapter for their own thread. `MainView` might not always be the page you think it is.

Comment: Thanks.  As a matter of fact, I only have one page at the moment.  How would I go about doing this, though?

Comment: Instead of explicitly using `CoreApplication.MainView`, just use the Dispatcher of the page you are currently on, ie `this.Dispatcher`. I also updated my answer a bit because this particular event is raised on a random thread; I had originally assumed you were using `Settings` from a different page entirely, but that needn't be the case to hit this error.

Comment: Thanks.  I accepted the answer, and will check this out.